# Issue with Grid command

Tags: export, grid-layouts, pdf-format

[image]

Dear all,

I've been trying to set prepare a grid with different charts for comparisons. The issue I have is that the first row of the grid has the legend distorted. The issue does not occur for subsequent rows. (see the elongated legend boxes?).

I defined a function to create a combination of two charts, then created a grid and exported it to pdf.

```
chartTrends[country_, percent_] := Module[
  {a, b},
  a = salesTrend[country, percent];
  b = Table[
    Labeled[Last[a][[i]], 
     If[Mod[i, 4] == 1, Rotate[headings[[i]], 90 Degree], None]], {i, 
     Range@Length@headings}];
  Grid[{{BarChart[b, ChartLayout -> "Percentile", 
      ChartStyle -> ColorData[35, "ColorList"], 
      PlotRegion -> {{0.10, 0.90}, {0.10, 0.90}}, ImageSize -> 1000, 
      ChartLegends -> 
       Placed[Style[#, FontSize -> Small] & /@ First[a], Right]], 
     BarChart[b, ChartStyle -> ColorData[35, "ColorList"], 
      PlotRegion -> {{0.10, 0.90}, {0.10, 0.90}}, 
      ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ImageSize -> 1000]}} ]]
```

This is what I used to create the grid and export it to pdf.

```
myGrid = Grid[ 
   Partition[
    Column[{"", Style[#, Bold, FontSize -> 36], "", 
        chartTrends[#, 0.9]}, Alignment -> Center] & /@ countryList, 
    4], Alignment -> Center, Frame -> All, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[LightGray]];
Export["myGrid2.pdf", myGrid]
```

I've tried with GraphicsGrid instead of Grid, but that creates other problems such as cropping the legend box.

Any clues?

Comment: Could you post a minimal and self-contained piece of code?

Comment: Hola Belisarius, here

Comment: Hola DiegoZviovich

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try defining `myGrid = Grid[..., ImageSize -> All]`. Consider for example the following test data

```
headings = Range[20];
countryList = Cases[CountryData["Countries"], 
   c_ /; CountryData[c, "BorderingCountries"] =!= {}, 1, 8];
salesTrend[c_, p_] := 
 With[{t = CountryData[c, "BorderingCountries"]},
  {t, RandomReal[1, {20, Length[t]}]}]
```

Then with

```
myGrid = Grid[Partition[
    Column[{"", Style[#, Bold, FontSize -> 36], "", 
        chartTrends[#, 0.9]}, Alignment -> Center] & /@ countryList, 
    4], Alignment -> Center, Frame -> All, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[LightGray], ItemSize -> All];

Export["myGrid2.pdf",myGrid]
```

I get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

compared to the original (Note the wrapping of Afghanistan plus the elongated legend)

[image: Mathematica graphics]